# Sharepoint powerapps autofill

Tags: canvas, sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

Given 2 sharepoint lists, which I am trying to make in canvas, a form where if I select an option from a drop-down menu, 2 text input fields will be given the values of that option by auto-filling.
Autofill also works, only after you submit these values will not be sent to the list.
For example, there is one list along with the job opportunity and job salary:

- IT, 100usd
- Engineer, 100usd

The second list is the scheduled date to start, weekly working hours and things like that, and in this list I should pick it up the first list data from form , send but cant send the values and I would ask for help in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values are not sent maybe it's because you are setting the form with data from other sources. You should use Filters or Choices with the same source as the form to get the values.
If you find problems on doing this you could also use a patch after the submit referring to the item with Form.LastSubmit()

Comment: Glad to help :)